# Ejabberd pending MUC messages

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat, ejabberd-module

I'm working on an ejabberd server and i'm trying to implement the typical push notifications for mobile devices.

At this moment, almost everything is already working well.

Except one thing: the pending messages to be read by a user.

The pending messages from the simple chats can be counted from the spool table, which contains all the messages pending to be delivered.

However, I don't know where I can find the pending messages from MUC chats.

Is there any way to know it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

In XMPP, MUC (MultiUser Chat) is based on presence. It means when you are not online, you are not supposed to receive messages. As such, there is no MUC pending messages.

You can use MUC Message Archive (MAM) to get access to MUC history.